# Jenkins podTemplate using dynamicPVC() is not creating a persistentVolume for my pipeline build

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, kubernetes-helm, jenkins-kubernetes, aws-ebs-csi-driver

I want to create large EBS volumes (e.g. 1TB) dynamically for each jenkins worker pod on my EKS cluster such that each `persistentVolume` representing an EBS volume only persists for the lifespan of the pod.

I can't change the size of the nodes on the EKS cluster,
so I'm trying to use external EBS volumes via the [ebs-csi-driver](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver) helm chart.

I can't seem to find a configuration for the `podTemplate` that enables dynamic provisioning of the `persistentVolumeClaim` and subsequent EBS `persistentVolume` for hosting my builds. The only way I'm able to successfully provision and mount EBS `persistentVolumes` dynamically to my worker pods is by using my own `persistentVolumeClaim` which I have to reference in the `podTemplate` and manually deploy using `kubectl apply -f pvc.yaml` and destroy `kubectl delete -f pvc.yaml` for each build cycle.

So far I've been able to provision one `persistentVolume` at a time using the following:

- `persistentVolumeClaim`:

  ```yaml
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    name: ebs-claim
    namespace: jenkins
  spec:
    accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
    storageClassName: ebs-sc
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 1000Gi
  ```
- `StorageClass`:

  ```yaml
  apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
  kind: StorageClass
  metadata:
    name: ebs-sc
  provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
  volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
  ```
- `podTemplate`:

  ```yaml
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Pod
  spec:
    serviceAccount: jenkins-sa
    securityContext:
      fsGroup: 1000
    containers:
    - name: jenkins-worker
      image: <some-image>
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      command:
      - cat
      tty: true
      securityContext:
        runAsGroup: 1000
        runAsUser: 1000
      volumeMounts:
      - name: build-volume
        mountPath: <some-mount-path>
    volumes:
    - name: build-volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: ebs-claim
  ```

  - I annotated the "jenkins-sa" `serviceAccount` with an AWS IAM Role ARN (`eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn`)
    with all the AWS IAM policies and trust-relationships needed to allow the jenkins worker Pod
    to provision an AWS EBS `persistentVolume` (as described in the [AWS ebs-csi-driver docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/csi-iam-role.html)).

Once the pipeline is started, and the jenkins worker pod is executing a build,
I'm able to ssh into it and confirm that the external EBS volume is mouted to the build directory using `df`.
Happy days!

However, I noticed the `persistentVolume` provisioned by the jenkins worker pod was lingering around
after the build finished and the pod destroyed. Apparently this is because the `PersistentVolumeClaim`
needs to be deleted before the `persistentVolume` it's bound to can be released (see [here](https://saturncloud.io/blog/kubernetes-the-correct-way-to-delete-persistent-volumes-pv/) for details).

After some digging it looks like I need to specify a `dynamicPVC()` in either the
`volumes` or `workspaceVolume` spec in the `podTemplate` yaml.
However I'm struggling to find documentation around dynamic `PersistentVolumeClaim` provisioning
beyond the [jenkins kubernetes plugin page](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/).
Unfortunately when I try to create `persistentVolumeClaims` dynamically like this
it doesn't work and just uses the maximum storage that the node can provision (which is limited to 20Gi).

- Updated `podTemplate`:

  ```yaml
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Pod
  spec:
    serviceAccount: jenkins-sa
    workspaceVolume:
      dynamicPVC:
        accessModes: ReadWriteOnce
        requestsSize: 800Gi
        storageClassName: ebs-sc
    securityContext:
      fsGroup: 1000
    containers:
    - name: jenkins-worker
      image: <some-image>
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      command:
      - cat
      tty: true
      securityContext:
        runAsGroup: 1000
        runAsUser: 1000
  ```

I am expecting a new `PersistentVolumeClaim` and `PersistentVolume` to be created
by the `podTemplate` when I start my build pipeline, and subsequently destroyed
when the pipeline finishes and the pod released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to [Saifeddine Rajhi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77182882/22415851) for pointing me in the right direction!

After investigating how the Jenkins helm-chart implements its `StatefulSet` in the [jenkinsci repo](https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/jenkins/templates/jenkins-controller-statefulset.yaml) and looking at [similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61480357/persistentvolumeclaim-workspace-for-jenkins-slave) around provisioning `persistentVolumes` dynamically for jenkins worker pods, I achieved the behavior I was looking for by specifying `dynamicPVC` with the workspace `workspaceVolume` argument as shown here:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            yaml podTemplate
            workspaceVolume dynamicPVC(accessModes: 'ReadWriteOnce', requestsSize: "1000Gi", , storageClassName: "ebs-sc")
        }
    }
...
}
```

I then just point my build directory to the default agent workspace directory where the dynamically provisioned EBS volume is mounted to in my container (`/home/jenkins/agent`).

---

Update (`30/11/2023`) following comment from [Bernard Halas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7772227/bernard-halas). Thanks for your input! Given that `workspaceVolume` is not a supported pod spec API element, then it seems the `podTemplate` approach doesn't support dynamic provisioning of `PVCs` so is not appropriate for my use-case and certainly explains why that approach wasn't working.

Comment: at least 4 errors in your last code snippet:
1. `s/workspacevolume/workspaceVolume`, i.e. notice upper-case
2. `s/- dynamicPVC/  dynamicPVC`, i.e. `workspaceVolume` doesn't take a list, but a dict/map
3. `s/workspaceVolumes/workspaceVolume`, i.e. it's singular, not plural
4. `workspaceVolume` is not a supported pod spec API element, it's Jenkins only

Answer (score 1):

you use k8s 1.23+, then this is possible for `StatefulSets`, i.e if you can change pods by `StatefulSets`.

The [PersistentVolumeClaim retention](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#persistentvolumeclaim-retention) feature configures the volume retention behavior that applies when the StatefulSet is deleted with the field `whenDeleted`

So when PersistentVolumeClaims (PVCs) generated from the StatefulSet spec template will be deleted automatically when the `StatefulSet is deleted` or pods in the StatefulSet are scaled down.

```
kind: StatefulSet
...
spec:
  persistentVolumeClaimRetentionPolicy:
    whenDeleted: Delete
    whenScaled: Delete
...
```

Also, add the `reclaimPolicy: Delete` field in the `StorageClass` resource which determines what happens to the Persistent Volumes (PVs) associated with that StorageClass when they are dynamically provisioned and later released.

As a result:

- When a PV associated with this StorageClass is dynamically provisioned and later released, the PV and the underlying storage resources are automatically deleted.
- This means that when the associated PVC is deleted, both the PV and the underlying storage are automatically cleaned up.